# Getting Every File in a Windows Directory

Tags: python, windows, directory

I have a folder in Windows 7 which contains multiple `.txt` files. How would one get every file in said directory as a list?

Comment: Do you want the list of **files** (not pathnames), e.g. `a.dat b.dat...` not `C:\DIRNAME\SUBDIR\a.dat ....`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`os.listdir(".")`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list the contents of the current directory ("."):

```
for name in os.listdir("."):
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        print(name)
```

If you want the whole list as a Python list, use a *list comprehension*:

```
a = [name for name in os.listdir(".") if name.endswith(".txt")]
```

Answer (score 18):

All of the answers here don't address the fact that if you pass `glob.glob()` a Windows path (for example, `C:\okay\what\i_guess\`), it does not run as expected. Instead, you need to use `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

glob_path = Path(r"C:\okay\what\i_guess")
file_list = [str(pp) for pp in glob_path.glob("**/*.txt")]
```

Comment: This solution works for windows. But will it also work in linux? Need my code to be portable

Comment: It will work for Linux. Path is more portable than Glob

Comment: The last line is simpler and [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790848/fastest-way-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-list/64512225#64512225) to write `file_list = list(glob_path.glob("**/*.txt"))`

Answer (score 15):

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir('c:/mydir')
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
```

Comment: Why os.chdir? Consider `glob.glob(r'c:\mydir\*.txt')`

Comment: @John Machin: absolutely true, that's another way to do it.

Comment: It's also a way to do it without the unnecessary unasked-for side effect of changing [one of] the current working director[y|ies].

Comment: @JohnMachin: because that's what the question asked for: the list of **files** (not pathnames)

Answer (score 2):

```
import fnmatch
import os

return [file for file in os.listdir('.') if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt')]
```

Comment: isn't return only used in a function?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the current directory, use os.listdir.

```
>>> os.listdir('.') # get the files/directories
>>> [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir('.')] # gets the absolute paths
>>> [x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(x)] # only files
>>> [x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith('.txt')] # files ending in .txt only
```

You can also use os.walk if you need to recursively get the contents of a directory. Refer to the python documentation for [os.walk.](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)