# How to read in a directory of images with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, directory, glob

I'm trying to read this directory of `jpg` images and add them to a list but the list is empty when I run this code:

```
import glob
import cv2
cv_img = []
for img in glob.glob("E:/project/file/*.jpg"):
    n= cv2.imread(img)
    cv_img.append(n)
```

Comment: You will confuse everyone if you call your directory `file` !

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5629272/2836621

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to read each image into a list. Also ensure that the **relative path** you're passing in to glob exists otherwise the list may be empty

```
import cv2
import glob

images = [cv2.imread(image) for image in glob.glob("images/*.jpg")]

for image in images:
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

Comment: but i need them in a list. .. and nothing is showing anyways

Comment: The images are in the list, if you `print(len(images))`, you should get the number of loaded images. Your path directory is probably incorrect or invalid so its not reading in any images. Note the path is a relative path

Comment: well i tried length already and it was empty . guess check on the path . it maybe cuz in jupyter notebook.

Comment: I'm 99% sure its a problem with either the path or the mage does not exist