# Using glob to find all csv files in folder and subfolder but return list is empty

Tags: python, csv, glob

So my ultimate goal is to add the data from multiple .csv files to a dataframe in Jupyter notebook.
I have been trying each piece first before I add them together but can't get past just getting the filenames. There are other non-csv files in the folders that I want to ignore.

I have a file with the following structure. The **bold** ones are the ones I want:

*directory*: E:\Grad School\Research\Pearl_River\Data_Collection\Previous_work\CRMS_Data

| -Full_Accretion
**| -Full_Accretion\Full_Accretion.csv**
| -Full_Accretion\RESTORE_disclaimer.txt
| -Full_Discrete_Hydrographic
**| -Full_Discrete_Hydrographic\Full_Accretion.csv**
| -Full_Discrete_Hydrographic\RESTORE_disclaimer.txt
| -Full_Marsh_Vegetation
**| -Full_Marsh_Vegetation\Full_Accretion.csv**
| -Full_Marsh_Vegetation\RESTORE_disclaimer.txt
(plus more but that doesn't really matter)

I have read through so many glob returning empty list questions and I've tried many iterations of code. I verified the files exist, that I spelled things correctly, that the path is correct. I've tried string literal or using the escape char. It only returns an empty list.

Here are the latest iterations

```
#Combine all the CRMS data into one dataframe
import os
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path

dfs = []
fdir = r'E:\Grad School\Research\Pearl_River\Data_Collection\Previous_work\CRMS_Data'
ftype = '*.csv'
all_files = [os.path.basename(i) for i in glob(r'E:\Grad 
School\Research\Pearl_River\Data_Collection\Previous_work\CRMS_Data\*.csv')]

#Get file names
#for path, subdir, files in os.walk(fdir):
#    for file in glob(os.path.join(fdir, ftype)):
#        all_files.append(file)
print(all_files)

#Get data
#for file in all_files:
#    data = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None)
#    dfs.append(data)

#Add data to dataframe
#df = pd.concat(dfs)
#df.head(5)
```

The stuff that is commented out is other things I've tried.
os.getcwd() returns 'C:\Users\w****\OneDrive - The University of Southern Mississippi\Research\Python' but I'm not trying to access the working directory.

This also did not work. Same result, empty list.

```
os.chdir(r'E:\Grad School\Research\Pearl_River\Data_Collection\Previous_work\CRMS_Data')
all_files = [f for file in glob('*/.csv', recursive=True)]
```

or

```
os.chdir(r'E:\Grad School\Research\Pearl_River\Data_Collection\Previous_work\CRMS_Data')
all_files = [f for file in glob(r'*\.csv', recursive=True)]
```

I have tried a lot of different things and I've been staring at it too long. The loop that is commented out also returns an empty list even with all kinds of iterations of r'*.csv', r'*.csv', r'/*.csv' in both the fdir and ftype.

So then lastly, I put it into Spyder (through Anaconda) so I could use the debugger and I noticed, for the first loop that is commented out, the following:
On the first pass of the outer loop, it sees the subfolders and puts those in subdir and files is blank.
Then it moves into the first subfolder, 'Full_Accretion', and also shows the files in files=[].
There is no file variable listed though and that is the one that is supposed to be appended to the list.
So I changed it to this:

```
for path, subdir, files in os.walk(fdir):
    for file in files:
        all_files.append(file)
```

It gave me filenames but it's all of them and not just the csv. I added *.csv into the fdir name and it gave me an empty list again.

I have not used glob much in the past so it's very likely user error. What am I missing? Thanks! (any missing not directly related imports such as pandas, are in the cells above this one)

Comment: Change `'*/.csv'` to `'*/*.csv'`.

Comment: @blhsing That did it! Thank you. I was hitting my head against the wall for hours lol

Comment: @Liraell, glad you figured it out. Will you please move your edited solution into its own answer and accept that answer to "close this question"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bhlsing gave me the missing piece. It ended up either not adding the full path if I used the one-liner or would loop too many times and have duplicates for the loop. I figured it out and here is what finally worked:

```
import os
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd


all_files = []
fdir = r'E:\Grad 
School\Research\Pearl_River\Data_Collection\Previous_work\CRMS_Data'

fnames = [os.path.basename(i) 
         for i in glob(r'E:\Grad School\Research\Pearl_River\
         Data_Collection\Previous_work\CRMS_Data\*\*.csv')
         ]

#Get file names
for fname in fnames:
    filename = os.path.join(fdir, fname)
    all_files.append(filename)
print(all_files)
```

It's probably not pythonic; I'm self-taught and still learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the edit to your question, I don't understand why you take the filename (os.path.basename) and then concatenate it with the base dir/folder name: that will cut out any intermediate directories the CSVs were found in.

Consider this simple file tree:

```
- base_dir
 - a
    bar.csv
    foo.txt
 - b
    baz.csv
```

Running:

```py
import os
from glob import glob


all_files = []
fdir = "base_dir"

fnames = [os.path.basename(i) for i in glob("base_dir/*/*.csv")]

# Get file names
for fname in fnames:
    filename = os.path.join(fdir, fname)
    all_files.append(filename)

print(all_files)
```

prints:

```py
[
    'base_dir/bar.csv', 
    'base_dir/baz.csv',
]
```

Given your original question, I think you can get away with something as simple as:

```py
all_csvs = glob("base_dir/*/*.csv")
```

or:

```py
for fname in glob("base_dir/*/*.csv"):
    # do something w/fname
    print(fname)
```

Your sample files only show you care about CSVs named Full_Accretion.csv. If that isn't just an artifact of a very small, sample set of names, glob can reflect that:

```py
glob("base_dir/*/Full_Accretion.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally have time to go back and look at this again and I tried all the examples you gave and they all still only return an empty list. I have no idea why. There are more files other than 'Full_Accretion.csv', I just didn't want to list them all so I didn't try the last line you suggested. I'm sure it's something I'm doing but I don't know what it is. Thanks for your time! @Zach

Comment: As a side note, I was able to use some of your solutions in another folder that did not have any subfolders. It's a completely different dataset but it saved me some time, Thanks! @Zach

Comment: @Liraell, you're welcome. I also keep forgetting how the difference between Windows and non-Windows can affect code that from my non-Windows perspective "should just work". Maybe this will help, now, or in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629242/getting-every-file-in-a-windows-directory. Good luck continuing to learn Python!

Comment: I'm not sure if I should be happy or a little salty to be honest. The fix I needed was on that question. lol down in the comments someone mentions glob doesn't act right on windows and suggested a fix and it worked. Now I know! But I might also be crying XD (this one:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53162818/22547051)

Comment: Should I actually change my accepted answer and put the link to that? I'm not sure how it works exactly with that. @Zach

Comment: @Liraell, if the other question and answer cover both your need and solution, then the question you created is a duplicate. I think the better thing to do would be to just delete this question entirely, and if you haven’t already go vote for both the other question and the answer that worked for you. And yeah, software definitely has its blood-sweat-and-TEARS moments 