# Convert Any Iterable to Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, iterable

This just *has* to be a dupe, but I just didn't find any existing instance of this question...

What is the easiest way to convert any iterable to an array in Python (ideally, without importing anything)?

**Note**: Ideally, if the input is an array then it shouldn't duplicate it (but this isn't required).

Comment: What is an array, please link to the docs?

Comment: @bradley Oh shoot, don't tell me Python doesn't have arrays!?! I thought `()` were lists and `[]` were arrays...

Comment: Python does have arrays (see my answer), but they are not the same as lists. () are used for tuples.

Comment: `()` is tuple `[]` is list, `{}` is dict :)

Comment: @jena, @bradley: Ah thanks. If you happen to know Scheme -- so Python's tuples are the same thing as Scheme's vectors?

Comment: I have never used Scheme, but if I'm not mistaken, Scheme's vectors are mutable, aren't they? Tuples in Python are immutable, so there's a difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to convert an iterator to a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790848/fastest-way-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-list)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by array. If you really mean array and not list or the like, then you should be aware that arrays are containers of elements of the same (basic) type (see http://docs.python.org/library/array.html), i.e. not all iterables can be converted into an array. If you mean list, try the following:

```
l = list(iterable)
```

Answer (score 4):

If by "array" you mean a list, how about:

```
list(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `[e for e in iterable]`?

And, to satisfy the extra requirement:

`iterable if isinstance(iterable,list) else [e for e in iterable]`

Comment: `[e for e in iterable]` is better written as `list(iterable)`.

Answer (score 2):

The [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) function takes an iterable as an argument and returns a list. Here's an example:

```
>>> rng = xrange(10)
>>> rng
xrange(10)
>>> list(rng)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This won't create a list of lists, either:

```
>>> list(list(rng))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, arrays and lists are more or less the same thing in python.  So a list comprehension will do the job:

```
  ary = [ i for i in yourthing ]
```