# len throws with 'dict_keyiterator' has no len() when calculating outgoing and incoming edges in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am implementing a graph manipulation script and I was puzzled with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".....py", line 12, in <module>
    print(len(graph.predecessors(i)), len(graph.successors(i)))
>>TypeError: object of type 'dict_keyiterator' has no len()<<
```

This is the code:

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.DiGraph()

for i in range(10):
  graph.add_node(i)

for i in range(9):
  graph.add_edge(i, i+1)

for i in range(10):
  print(len(graph.predecessors(i)), len(graph.successors(i)))
```

What is this `dict_keyiterator` and how to fix my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was eventually fixable by converting the iterator to a list:

```
print(len(list(graph.predecessors(i))), len(list(graph.successors(i))))
```

Yakym Pirozhenko suggested an alternative approach deemed faster so I checked:

```
def f1():
  for i in range(10):
    len(list(graph.predecessors(i)))

def f2():
  for i in range(10):
    sum(1 for _ in graph.predecessors(i))

print(timeit.timeit(f1, number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit(f2, number=100000))
```

And got:

```
0.529827729
0.652576311
```

Clearly, the `len(list(...))` approach is faster here.
I was using: Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

---

After some searching I have found a question with a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161158/networkx-neighbor-set-not-printing) and a straightforward explanation [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2013-February/093767.html):

> In 2.x `iter(some_dict)` returns a dictionary-keyiterator (weird
> hyphen). In 3.x it's a `dict_keyiterator` (normal underscore).

So it seems that direct use of `iter(d)` where `d` is a `dict` results in the object of type `dict_keyiterator` in Python 3. This is one of 3 iterators replacing Python 2: `d.viewkeys()`, `d.viewitems()`, and `d.viewvalues()`:

> The corresponding iterators returned by `iter()` in 3.x are
> `dict_keyiterator`, `dict_itemiterator`, and `dict_valueiterator`.

Comment: You can use `sum(1 for _ in graph.predecessors(i))` instead of `len` + `list` to avoid creating new copies.