# NetworkX g.neighbors(n) dict_keyiterator error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to find all neighbors of a given node in a defined graph by using G.neighbors() function from NetworkX. I am setting my graph structure of the directed graph as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

#Define network structure
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('x','a', dependency=0.4)
G.add_edge('x','b', dependency=0.6)
G.add_edge('a','c', dependency=0.9)
G.add_edge('b','c', dependency=0.3)
G.add_edge('b','d', dependency=0.7)
G.add_edge('d','e', dependency=0.8)
G.add_edge('c','y', dependency=0.4)
G.add_edge('e','y', dependency=0.2)
G.add_node('x', value=20)
G.add_node('a', value=15)
G.add_node('b', value=35)
G.add_node('c', value=10)
G.add_node('d', value=15)
G.add_node('e', value=5)
G.add_node('y', value=15)
```

Now, I am trying to find all node neighbors of e.g. the node 'b', which should be 'c' and 'd'. I am using the following function:

```
print(G.neighbors('b'))
```

Now, Python throws out no error message but the following statement:

```
<dict_keyiterator object at 0x000001561D812950>
Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, it is not throwing out the neighbors of G.node('b') but this message. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: After checking, this question already has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161158/networkx-neighbor-set-not-printing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `graph.neighbors()` function returns an iterator object. This can be viewed as a list as we would normally view iterators:

```
>>> list(G.neighbors('b'))
['c', 'd']
```