# How to access the nodes in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am only getting `<dict_keyiterator object at 0x7f300ee69410>` printed; while I wish to print the neighbours of each node. Also, how to assign a number between 0-1 determining the sate of each of the neighbours.

So that the final information is something like ; node 5 has 4 neighbours which are 1,2,3,4 each with a state 0.1,0.4,0.6,0.8. I will further use these states in my calculations, so preferably an array containing this information will work. This maybe, a very trivial doubt but if someone can relate their answer with C language then it will be more than useful for me; as I am new to python!

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100,2)

for u in G.nodes():
    neighbors = nx.neighbors(G, u)
    print(neighbors)
```

Edit: Answer of printing error [Networkx neighbor set not printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161158/networkx-neighbor-set-not-printing)

Comment: I found the answer to the first question; i.e to use a list instead! `print(list(G.neighbors(u)))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161158/networkx-neighbor-set-not-printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neighbors` is an iterable. Without going into too much detail, iterables are the things you use in `for` loops.

To print out an iterable all at once, you can turn it into a list, if you know it's finite:

```
print(list(neighbors))
```

You can also use python's iterable unpacking syntax to pass each element individually to `print`:

```
print(*neighbors)
```

A more general, but sometimes more flexible approach is to run a loop over the iterable, and process each element independently:

```
for e in neighbors:
    print(e)
```