# Python function with list

Tags: python, list, function

learn python by myself. I made a function for filling list. But I have 2 variants, and I want to discover which one is better and why. Or they both awful anyway I want to know truth.

```
def foo (x):
    l = [0] * x
    for i in range(x):
        l[i] = i
    return l

def foo1 (x):
    l = []
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i)
    return l
```

Comment: I would say the second is more idiomatic and can be easily translated to a list-comprehension. But in this particular case you can actually just do `list(range(x))`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a performance perspective the first version `foo` is better:

```
%timeit foo(1000000)
# 52.4 ms ± 1.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit foo1(1000000)
# 67.2 ms ± 916 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

but the [pythonic way to unpack an iterator in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896860/pythonic-way-to-unpack-an-iterator-inside-of-a-list) will be:

```
list(range(x))
```

---

also is faster:

```
%timeit list(range(1000000))
# 26.7 ms ± 661 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```