# How do I take out an element from itertools.permutations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = permutations("hello",5)
```

This gives me a weird <> thing I don't understand. 
It seems to work to go

```
for i in perms:
    print(i)
```

But I don't want to run through all permutations as there are very many of them. 
So I want to be able to do something like

```
perms[index]
```

to give ("h","e","l","l","o").
But this breaks because it's "not subscriptable". So how do I get just ("h","e","l","l","o") from this?
Thank you!

Comment: So are you looking to parse all permutations and indeed ignore *some* of them, or do you have only a very limited number of permutations to generate, in which case `itertools.permutations` is probably not the best way to go?

Comment: That weird `<>` thing is an iterator

Comment: `perms = list(permutations("hello",5))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to convert an iterator to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790848/fastest-way-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-list)

Comment: Try to convert into a `list` by `list(perms)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the nth item of a generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300756/get-the-nth-item-of-a-generator-in-python)

Comment: @SayandipDutta the question is about not generating/parsing all permutations, so materializing the iterator as a list does not help I think.

Comment: I guess it's only an example, but just in case the OP really only wants to turn `"hello"` into `('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')`, they just need `tuple('hello')`...

Comment: @CorentinPane Yeah, I guess I misunderstood. But I am not entirely sure what the OP wants even now. For example I can't understand how would he be able to know which index contains `("h","e","l","l","o")`.

Comment: you could try `itertools.islice(perms, index, index+1)`

Comment: @furas same issue here, `islice` still goes through all previous permutations to find the one you need.

Comment: @CorentinPane yes, but it is better then using `list()`. if you want something better then you would have to write something similar to `permutations` from scratch

Comment: Thank you all for the help but I now realise I have far too many permutations for this to be a feasible strategy. Going to rethink and try a different method. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `nth` permutation of a sequence in lexicographic order without having to generate all of them, you can use this snippet adapted from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/126037-getting-nth-permutation-of-a-sequence/):

```py
from functools import reduce

def Factorial (n):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, n + 1), 1)

def GetNthPermutation (seq, index):
    seqc = list(seq[:])
    result = []
    fact = Factorial(len(seq))
    index %= fact
    while seqc:
        fact = fact // len (seqc)
        choice, index = index // fact, index % fact
        result += [seqc.pop(choice)]
    return result
```

which you can use like this:

```py
>>> print(GetNthPermutation(list("hello"), 3))
['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'l']
```