# Retrieve latest file with pathlib

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I primarily use pathlib over os for paths, however there is one thing I have failed to get working on pathlib.
If for example I require the latest created .csv within a directory I would use glob & os

```
import glob
import os

target_dir = glob.glob("/home/foo/bar/baz/*.csv")
latest_csv = max(target_dir, key=os.path.getctime)
```

Is there an alternative using pathlib only?
(I am aware you can yield matching files with `Path.glob(*.csv)`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it in just pathlib by doing the following:

A Path object has a method called stat() where you can retrieve things like creation and modify date.

```
from pathlib import Path

files = Path("./").glob("*.py")

latest_file = max([f for f in files], key=lambda item: item.stat().st_ctime)

print(latest_file)
```

Comment: A simplification in syntax is to replace `[f for f in files]` with `list(files)`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790848/fastest-way-to-convert-an-iterator-to-a-list/64512225#64512225

Comment: `max` takes any iterable, so you don't even need to convert it into a list first. `max(files, key=...)` should work just as well.